# Calcule $\int \sqrt{16-x^4}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Can this be solved by elementary methods?

Can $x ^ 4 = 4cos (y)?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is $$\frac{-x^5+16 \sqrt{16-x^4} F\left(\left.\sin
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right|-1\right)+16 x}{3 \sqrt{16-x^4}}$$ also non elementary.

Comment: Is it possible to calculate until you get to this solution?

Comment: This is the solution, if you choose to accept it, where the Elliptic integral function $F(\phi |k)$ is defined as $$F(\phi |k)=\int_0^\phi \frac1{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\theta}}\ d\theta.$$

Documentation can be found [here on WolframMathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegraloftheFirstKind.html).